# onMouseDown() and onMouseUp() not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this 2D button set up and I've added a 2D circle collider to it. And I've added the following script.

```
public UnityEvent upEvent;
public UnityEvent downEvent;


  public void OnMouseDown() {
    Debug.Log("Down");
    print("down");
    downEvent?.Invoke();
}

  public void OnMouseUp() {
     Debug.Log("Up");
     upEvent?.Invoke();
}
```

but when I click on this button, nothing happens. I don't get any errors. Nor do I see any Debug message or see the events get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you have another UI object that's blocking it. For example, an invisible panel that's also a raycast target that is in front of the button may be blocking the click interaction from occuring.

Comment: yes , because the item in question is also a button, and when I call the event in OnClick, it works.

Comment: could it be because the button is inside a canvas???

Comment: Interesting! I have an idea - Is your button using an Image component to render the sprite? If so, then the reason it's not working for you is because Images render on the Canvas position, which is different from the world position. So `onMouseDown()` works by doing a raycast. If the button uses a sprite, then if you click it, it's gonna work. But if you're using an Image component instead, it won't show up where it really is in world space, and so your raycast is just gonna go off into space. If you change it to a `SpriteRenderer` component, align it with your camera, and try clicking it.

Comment: Yes it's an image component

Comment: Well then that's why it doesn't work. Either keep using the `Image` component and change it to use the `onClick()` event that comes with the button, or in order to use the `onMouseDown()` functions, move the component to where you want it in world space and use a `SpriteRenderer` instead.

Comment: wouldn't there be scaling issues when  I move it into worldspace and use a sprite renderer?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation:

> This function is not called on objects that belong to Ignore Raycast layer.
>
> This function is called on Colliders marked as Trigger if and only if Physics.queriesHitTriggers is true.

Check that your collider is marked as trigger and that the `queriesHitTriggers` is true.

Comment: The collider is marked as trigger, How do I set queriesHitTriggers to true?

Comment: It is a static variable. Just -> `Physics.queriesHitTriggers = true;`

Comment: I added it to the start function of my button. 
Still nothing.